# ¿Cómo muestro una imagen desde MySQL en PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Tengo el código para insertar, pero lo que quiero es mostrar una imagen por medio del id, ¿cómo lo puedo hacer?.

Tengo una consulta pero me da NOID. Se las muestra y si me pueden orientar por favor. Saludos, les dejo mi código.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['id'])){ 
    $id = $_GET['id']; 
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die ("ERROR AL CONECTAR"); 
    $db_select = mysql_select_db("imagen") or die ("ERROR AL SELECCIONAR DB"); 

    $q = "SELECT * FROM tabla_imagen WHERE id = '$id'"; 
    $result = mysql_query($q, $link) or die ("Error al consultar"); 

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
    echo $row["imagen"]; 
    } 

    mysql_free_result($result); 
    } else { 
        echo 'NO ID'; 
        } 
?>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Las funciones mysql en php ( 7.* ) están obsoletas, busca sobre Mysqli y PDO (si piensas usar las nuevas versiones de php 7.*). Con respecto a tu pregunta, asegurate que en la url se esté colocando algo así: /miscript.php?id=1

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu sugerencia. Gracias :)

Comment: El mensaje `NO ID` te aparecerá únicamente si no llamas a tu URL agregando la ID en la URL de la siguiente manera: `http://tu_url/tu_php.php?id=...`

Comment: ¿Conseguiste solucionar el problema?

Answer (score 0):

El mensaje `NO ID` te aparecerá únicamente si no llamas a tu URL agregando la ID en la URL de la siguiente manera: `http://tu_url/tu_php.php?id=...`

Podemos arreglar un poco tu código para que muestre información más precisa y, además, protegerla contra los [nefastos efectos](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) de la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL) haciendo uso de [`mysql_real_escape_string()`](http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string):

```
<?php
/* Comprobamos si se envió por GET en la URL el campo "id" */
if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
  /* Escapamos el contenido de "id" (estaría bien comprobar
      que su contenido es adecuado) */
  $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['id']);
  $link = mysql_connect(
    "localhost",
    "root",
    ""
  ) or die ("ERROR AL CONECTAR: " . mysql_error());
  $db_select = mysql_select_db(
    "imagen"
  ) or die ("ERROR AL SELECCIONAR DB: " . mysql_error());
  $q = "SELECT * FROM tabla_imagen WHERE id = '$id'";
  $result = mysql_query(
    $q,
    $link
  ) or die ("Error al consultar: " . mysql_error());
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo $row["imagen"];
  }
  mysql_free_result($result);
} else {
  /* En caso de no agregar el campo "id" a la URL mostramos
      una información más detallada del problema */
  echo '"ID" no introducida. Use "', $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ,'?id=N"';
}
```

**Como último consejo:** Usa consultas preparadas con [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) o [PDO/mysql](http://php.net/pdo-mysql). Abandona el uso de las funciones `mysql_*`. Están marcadas como obsoletas en PHP 5.5 y eliminadas completamente de PHP en la versión 7.0.